# Logging of category org.hibernate.cache in hibernate 4.1 is not working

Tags: hibernate, logging, ehcache

after migrating from **hibernate 3** to **hibernate 4.1.3** and getting everything, including general **hibernate logging**, to work, i ran into the following issue:

All the hibernate logging seems to work, except for the cache-related logging.
I am using ehcache (`org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`) for 2nd-level caching. The cache itselt is working properly (extracted cache statistics, seeing misses, hits, puts, ...).

I found hints to other categories (e.g. `org.hibernate.type`) not working in the past or still not working, but nothing related to cache-logging.

The application is using **slf4j** with **log4j** as logging implementation.
I can enable and disable other desired categories in `log4j.properties` without any problems.

Does anyone have an idea or further information on this, what it seems to be, issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by adding the level of "org.hibernate.cache" to TRACE. In logback that would be:

`<logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="TRACE"/>`